# development of sliding navigation tabs in android 1.3

Tags: android

I am building navigation tabs for my android app, but in android 1.3, various methods and classes are deprecated e.g.  ActionBarActivity,getcolor etc...

Please help me with some other way to design them, thanks

Comment: You have to show some code.

Comment: It would be nice if you could show some code about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) which allows you to create a navigation through horizontal tabs.